# Nautilus fast directory or file find

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

I would like to ask how I can put long file path to Nautilus window for fast change directory.
For example I am in home directory and from terminal have path to file which I need to see.
"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PythonCard/resource.py"

In M$ app I can put (copy/paste) directly this path and can see result in filemanager.

Is it posible also in nautilus? (I have Uuntu 16.04)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut, or in menu Go > Enter location.

Comment: Thank you wery much. It is litle secret function. My wisch is one small icon for this.

Comment: Try Nemo file browser, `sudo apt install nemo`,  there you can set a a location button in Preferences > Toolbar, it has also much more features than Nautilus.